# rxjs, How can I merge multiple subjects in to one Observable, but process them with different method

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have three `subject`. like this:

```js
const s1$ = new Subject()
const s2$ = new Subject()
const s3$ = new Subject()
```

these three subjects call `next()` emit same value: `const fruit = {id: 1, name: apple}`;

and, I have three methods to handle the logic **one to one correspondence** of the `subjects` call `next(fruit)` method.

```js
method1() {
  //called when s1$.next(fruit)
}

method2() {
  //called when s2$.next(fruit)
}

method3() {
  //called when s3$.next(fruit)
}
```

I want to implement this:

```js
// here maybe not Observable.merge, it's just a thinking.
Observable.merge(
  s1$,
  s2$,
  s3$
)
.doSomeOperator()
.subscribe(val => {
  //val could be s1$ emit, s2$ emit or s3$ emit
  //but the val is same, the fruit.

  //do some map like s1->method1, s2->method2, s3->method3, so I can omit if...else statement.
  const method = this.method1 | this.method2 | this.method3. 
  method();
})
```

How can I implement this, thanks.

Comment: Maybe `do` operator is what you need (http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do)

Answer (score 0):

Use map operator to add a distinguish sources.

```js
export class AppComponent  {

  s1(val) {
    console.log('s1', val);
  }

  s2(val) {
    console.log('s2', val);
  }

  constructor() {
    const s1= new Subject();
    const s2= new Subject();
    const m1= s1.map(val=> ({val, source:'s1'}));
    const m2 = s2.map(val=> ({val, source:'s2'}));

    Observable.merge(m1, m2)
    .subscribe(({val, source}) => {
      this[source](val);
    });

    s1.next('apple');
    s2.next('apple');
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not a fan of the above. this kind of string arguments invalidates all the type checking Typescript offers us. At least return the method directly, then

Answer (score 0):

If there are no priority order (given that no matter which `Subject` emits, you want to have the method called), I would suggest the following:

```typescript
// here maybe not Observable.merge, it's just a thinking.
Observable.merge(
  s1$.map((val) => ({fn: (arg) => this.method1(arg), val})),
  s2$.map((val) => ({fn: (arg) => this.method2(arg), val})),
  s3$.map((val) => ({fn: (arg) => this.method3(arg), val}))
)
.subscribe({fn, val}=> {
  fn(arg)
});
```

You can also execute them at the `map` operator. But well, it depends what you are trying to achieve here

Answer (score 0):

A small fix for the previous answer:

```
// here maybe not Observable.merge, it's just a thinking.
Observable.merge(
  s1$.pipe(
    map((val) => ({fn: (arg) => this.method1(arg), val})),
  ),
  s2$.pipe(
    map((val) => ({fn: (arg) => this.method2(arg), val})),
  )
  s3$.pipe(
    map((val) => ({fn: (arg) => this.method3(arg), val}))
  )
).subscribe(({fn, val}) => {
  fn(val)
});
```